# UPS API To Extract Activity Location

Tags: c#, xml, api, ups

I am trying to use the UPS API to extract the Activity Location using XML.  I have written this extract piece.

```
city = xml.Element("TrackResponse").Element("Package").Element("Activity").Element("ActivityLocation").Element("Address").Element("City")?.Value;
```

But everytime I run the syntax I get a debug error of:

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have checked the documentation and verified that I am using the proper XML data structure hierarchy, but am still not able to extract this element.  How should the syntax above be altered in order to extract the city from the UPS API?

And this is a screenshot from the UPS API that shows the XML Hierarchy to follow to extract my desired field.
[image]

**EDIT**
This is how the same field exists twice, (in this instance) I want to extract from `Package` parent element, but using `FirstOrDefault()` how can I select?

**Example 1**

```
<Shipment>
  <Shipper>
    <Address>
      <City>XXXX</City>
    </Address>
  </Shipper>
</Shipment>
```

**Example 2**

```
<Package>
  <Activity>
      <ActivityLocation>
        <Address>
          <City>....</City>
        </Address>
      </ActivityLocation>
  </Activity>
</Package>
```

Comment: There is no "TrackResponse" in xml.  Try descendants instead : city = (string)xml.Descendants("City").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @jdweng - there are 2 elements titled city in the full XML Schema.  Using FirstOrDefault() and your sample syntax, how can I set which element I want to select?

Comment: You have an array.  Probably more than one Package.  So something like this : var results = xml.Descendants("Package").Select(x => new { city = (string)x.Descendants("City).FirstOrDefault()}).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng - I am using a foreach loop to iterate each individual package and write results back to a SQL Server table.  See my edit on what I meant by having 2 elements titled city.

Comment: foreach(XElement package in xml.Descendants("Package"))
{
   city = (string)package.Descendants("City").FirstOrDefault();
}

Comment: @jdweng - I was using Element("City")?.Value; to check for NULL - what would be the best way to check for such using your above syntax?

Comment: I'm not use Value.  Value gives error when you have a null.  So to avoid error I'm casting the Element using (string).  You can also use (int) or (int?).

Comment: Excellent, if you post as answer I will accept as you have resolved my issue!

Comment: Don't need the points.

Comment: Well thank you greatly!!!!!

Comment: You have to learn when to use Element(), Elements(), and Descendants().  Element() is singular and only gets first child, Elements() returns an array and  Descendants() return an array.  So when you get an array and only need one item then use FirstOrDefault() to get one item.